# Clicking text to check checkboxes in one table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

i have rows inside container with text header and checkboxes in every column, i want to make when the header is clicked the checkboxes below inside the same container become checked but the other in different container not affected(still in their original state checked or checked). Here's the screen shoot for the layout:
[image]

here's the html code for first container:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5" style="background-color:green;"><P class="member">Member</p></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:green;"><P class="add">ToogleAdd</p></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:green;"><P class="edit">ToogleEdit</p></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:green;"><P class="delete">ToogleDel</p></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="checkbox" name="auth100" value="auth100" id="auth100" onclick ="togAuth1()">New Member + Kit Purchase</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="addAuth100" value="addAuth100" id="addAuth100">Add</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="editAuth100" value="editAuth100" id="editAuth100">Edit</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="delAuth100" value="delAuth100" id="delAuth100">Delete</input></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="checkbox" name="auth101" value="auth101" id="auth101">New Member Registration</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="addAuth101" value="addAuth101" id="addAuth101">Add</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="editAuth101" value="editAuth101" id="editAuth101">Edit</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="delAuth101" value="delAuth101" id="delAuth101">Delete</input></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="checkbox" name="auth102" value="auth102" id="auth102">Member Data Maintenance</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="addAuth102" value="addAuth102" id="addAuth102">Add</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="editAuth102" value="editAuth102" id="editAuth102">Edit</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="delAuth102" value="delAuth102" id="delAuth102">Delete</input></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="checkbox" name="auth103" value="auth103" id="auth103">Member Registration Listing</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="addAuth103" value="addAuth103" id="addAuth103">Add</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="editAuth103" value="editAuth103" id="editAuth103">Edit</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="delAuth103" value="delAuth103" id="delAuth103">Delete</input></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="checkbox" name="auth104" value="auth104" id="auth104">Geneology Listing</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="addAuth104" value="addAuth104" id="addAuth104">Add</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="editAuth104" value="editAuth104" id="editAuth104">Edit</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="delAuth104" value="delAuth104" id="delAuth104">Delete</input></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="checkbox" name="auth105" value="auth105" id="auth105">Member Rank Report</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="addAuth105" value="addAuth105" id="addAuth105">Add</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="editAuth105" value="editAuth105" id="editAuth105">Edit</input></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="delAuth105" value="delAuth105" id="delAuth105">Delete</input></div>
</div>
```

html code for second container:

```
<div class="container-fluid">  <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-5" style="background-color:green;"><P class="member">Member</p></div>
<div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:green;"><P class="add">ToogleAdd</p></div>
<div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:green;"><P class="edit">ToogleEdit</p></div>
<div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:green;"><P class="delete">ToogleDel</p></div></div><div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-5"><input type="checkbox" name="auth100" value="auth100" id="auth200">New Member + Kit Purchase</input></div>
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="addAuth100" value="addAuth100" id="addAuth200">Add</input></div>
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="editAuth100" value="editAuth100" id="editAuth200">Edit</input></div>
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="delAuth100" value="delAuth100" id="delAuth200">Delete</input></div></div></div>
```

here's the unfinished jquery code:

```
$('.container-fluid').each(function(){$('.row:first').each(function(){$('.member').click(function(){


});
$('.add').click(function(){

});
$('.edit').click(function(){

});
$('.delete').click(function(){

});  });});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add classes to all the checkboxes (`.edit_check, .add_check` etc.) 
Then change them all using Javascript or JQ.

```
$('.add').click(function(){
   if ($(".add_check").is(":checked")){ //if at least one is checked
       document.getElementByClassName(".add_check").checked = false; //JS version
       $(".add_check").prop("checked", false); //JQ version
   } else {
       document.getElementByClassName(".add_check").checked = true; //JS version
       $(".add_check").prop("checked", true); //JQ version
   }

});
```

Comment: how to uncheck all the checkboxes by click the header again ?

Comment: @Wallflower I updated my answer with `if-else` condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".member").click(function(){
        $("input[id^='auth']").each(function(){
                 $(this).prop("checked",true);
        });
});
```

on header click all ids starting with auth are checked.

Comment: well it makes all the checkbox in different container become affected too

Comment: is the row count fixed in each container

Comment: its different each container contain different number of rows, and how to uncheck all the checkboxes by clicking the header again ?

Comment: Can you post code in different container?
to uncheck make prop checked false instead of true

Comment: i've edited my question check it out, yeah i know just change it to true but how can u toggle the header text so it can check and uncheck checkboxes? i've tried putting `if$(this).checked` condition, but its not working